# Firebase Storage URL error due to invalid Token - Android

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm having trouble retrieving the icon´s images from Firebase Storage to my `Xamarin.Android` app because the (Dynamic) Token that is appended to the URL of the images eventually changes (for security reasons).

The icons in the app are loaded using `FFImageLoading`, but when passing the static link (uri) that is stored in the source code, the ImageView does not show the icons because the token expired (it is no longer valid).

Image link example in Firebase Storage (uri):

```
https: // firebasestorage. googleapis. com / v0 / b / test-7c916. appspot. com / o / IconoSplash.png? alt = media & token = b207cb31-5ad5-48e1-86ac-1dcb07ee6021
```

Expired token that is at the end of the URL (uri) mentioned above:

```
b207cb31-5ad5-48e1-86ac-1dcb07ee6021
```

Reading Image in ImageView with FFImageLoading:

```
var Iconx = FindViewById <ImageView> (Resource.Id.IconoSplash);
ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl (uri)
.Retry (5, 250)
.Into (Iconox);
```

**Question:**
How can this be resolved?

Is it possible that the Firebase Storage URL is static (i.e. not constantly changing)?

Or How do I get a new valid Token?

(Can´t find much info regarding this issue and Xamarin Android, so any tip will help.)

Comment: Edited for better understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are not sensitive you can set the bucket public and access the images using this URL:

```
https://YOURPROYECTNAME.storage.googleapis.com/YOURFOLDER/YOURIMAGE.png
```

This way you get what you want, a `static URL` and no `Token` needed, but be advise that this is not too secure. Well, is actually pretty insecure because anybody can access (see) those images.

Let me know if you can work with this.